# How can we make the Allocation Profile procedure in Chrome Dev Tools terminate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find memory leaks in a React.js application. I've been using tools in Chrome such as Heap Snapshots, Allocation Profiles and Allocation Timelines. 
When I use Allocation Timeline to capture a timeline, the recording does not stop and clicking on any part of the graph shows nothing:
[image]

I've tried searching about this problem. Did not find any solution yet.

I expect the recording to stop at some point and constructor/objects to be shown when clicked on any part of the allocation graph. Right now it does not terminate and shows nothing when clicked on graph.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the red **Record** button at the top-left?

Comment: oh my bad! actually yes, it did stop the recording!